# unable to use terminal after SSH to windows server using FreeSSHD

Tags: linux, ssh, freesshd

I have setup a SSH server on windows using freeSSHD.

From Linux machine I run the following command to SSH to Windows:

```
SSH -i mykey myuser@mymachine
```

The moment I hit the **enter** button, **I no longer can type anything in the terminal as all the text in the terminal disarranged, but I can see it was successfully connected to the windows server.**

Comment: I presume this is a problem? (you might want to reword the question)... Have you checked the Windows box for a popup dialog / error message? What does `^D` do?

Comment: Have you tried the official forums for that product? You can make a bug report there: http://www.freesshd.com/index.php?ctt=forum

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without seeing *how* the text is "disarranged" - it may be as simple as the Windows end-of-line sequence vs. the Linux end-of-line sequence, or a mismatching TERM type, or something completely different.